# set width of left div relative to screen

Tags: lightning, css, slds, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I have created a lightning component which has the two div-left div & right div.

```
<div class="float-left-area">
</div>
<div class="float-right-area">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.THIS.float-left-area  {
          width: 78%;
          float: left;
          }

.THIS.float-right-area {
          width: 21%;
          float: left;
          background-color: white;
          padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
          margin: 0px 5px 0px 9px;
          border-radius: 5px;
          }
```

I want the width of the left div to be 78% and right div to be 21% of the screen it is displayed on. I tried using vh but it didn't give me the output I wanted. How can I set this div width relative to screen?

Comment: you might consider posting this to stackoverflow as this sounds like a general css issue that's not specific to salesforce. no harm in asking it here, just less css experts to draw on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using slds, you can use a grid:

```
<lightning:layout>
  <lightning:layoutItem size="3">
  </lightning:layoutItem>
  <lightning:layoutItem size="9">
  </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning: layout>
```